# how to change Azure cognitive search logic from OR based to AND based

Tags: azure, full-text-search, azure-cognitive-search

I am using Azure cognitive search for a RAG based solution. On giving the search keywords like " vendors with apple, oranges and lemons". It is returning vendors who supply either of the three and not the vendors who supplies all three.

Basically how to change the search logic from OR to AND.

Current result : Vendors who supply Apples OR Oranges OR Lemons.
I need : Vendors who supply Apples AND Oranges AND Lemons.

I am skimming through the documentation for changing this approach. changed the search_mode to all
"searchMode=all"

Also tried search=Apple+oranges

I am skimming through the documentation for changing this approach. changed the search_mode to all
"searchMode=all"

Also tried search=Apple+oranges

Similarly with "Apple" AND "oranges"

the data is not tabular or small files. The details are spread in  documents. but the key words are unique.

I also need the metadata, or the name of the document that has this match. However its always returning all the documents with the key words.

Comment: Did changing search mode to “all” work?

Comment: No, as mentioned in the question, I had already tried that.

Answer (score 1):

I have created an index and used below sample data:

```py
documents = {
    "value": [
        {"@search.action": "upload", "VendorId": "1", "VendorName": "Vendor 1", "Fruits": ["Apple", "Orange", "Lemon"]},
        {"@search.action": "upload", "VendorId": "2", "VendorName": "Vendor 2", "Fruits": ["Apple", "Banana"]},
        {"@search.action": "upload", "VendorId": "3", "VendorName": "Vendor 3", "Fruits": ["Orange", "Lemon"]},
    ]
}
```

For your specific case, you can use the `AND` operator to ensure that all your conditions must be met and remember to set `searchMode=all` if you're using the simple query syntax and want to optimize searches for precision instead of recall.

With Below search query I was able to get required results:

```py
query = {
    "search": "Apple AND Banana",
    "searchMode": "all",
    "count": True,
    "top": 5,
    "queryType":"full"
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. However its not working for me. for my usecase i hav eto search within text documents, like pdfs or doc files. like resume search. I tried by giving the AND statement as well but no luck

Comment: is there a way to filter the document or metadata according to the search?

Comment: You can add filters to query, check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-filters) for details.

Answer (score 0):

The searchMode=all setting should resolve this as it changes the default behavior from an ‘OR’ to an ‘AND’ logic between search terms.

If you’re looking for exact phrases or specific combinations of words, you can also use quotation marks around the phrases. For example, search="apple" AND "oranges" AND "lemons”.